# React Laravel 405 method not allowed

Tags: reactjs, laravel, routes, single-page-application, http-status-code-405

My application has React frontend and Laravel backend. React is deployed in S3 bucket, while Laravel is deployed in EC2 instance. In almost every case, things work perfect on my local and somehow fail in production. It has been driving me crazy. The most recent problem right now is that the route /api/user doesn't fetch user data on production because it says POST method is not allowed. It's not true because on local it's working perfect.

This is the code from production:

React Frontend:

```
const user = await api()
    .get(CSRF)
    .then(() => api().post(API_USER, body, config));
console.log('user', user);
```

Laravel Backend:

```
Route::post('/user', function(Request $request){
 $email = $request->email;
 $user = User::where('email', $email)->get();
 return $user;
});
```

Route list on EC2 production:
[image]

I already ran `php artisan routes:clear` and `php artisan optimize:clear`

Could anyone please help why this might be happening?

PS. I am using this way to fetch user data because on my local, after login, payload returned data but on production payload data was always empty. No idea why.

EDIT

Screenshot of console:
[image]

Network:
[image]

Postman:
[image]

Comment: The 405 Method Not Allowed indicates that Laravel can't find the route for the method requested. So can you please share api url which is used in react?

Comment: POST http://18.234.204.118/api/user 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: In the routes list it shows that the route exist and POST method is literally the only one defined. So I really don't understand what the problem is here

Comment: What is your route file name? Did you create it in api.php route file?

Comment: Try adding a `.catch` block to your API request and checking the exact response from that. Also, ensure that you've configured `CORS` correctly.

Comment: @NimaPatel Yes, it's api.php

Comment: @Peppermintology if CORS config had a problem, wouldn't it also break on local? And the login and registration works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by restarting the EC2 instance and nginx.